# No bean named dataSource is defined

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 4 and I want to authenticate by querying the database. I have created Users and Authorities tables. My jdbc connection bean of datasource, is defined in a java file using annotations. My spring security configuration is in xml. I have read that the same contextLoader is being used and hence there should be no problem loading all the beans. But, how do I import the dataSource bean defined in the java file, into my spring security config file?

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;
import org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean;
import org.mybatis.spring.annotation.MapperScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;

@Configuration
@MapperScan("com.iz.acsadmin.dao")
public class DataConfig{
    @Bean(name = "dataSource" )
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.3:5432/Student");
        dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
        dataSource.setPassword("admin");
        return dataSource;
    }
...
```

The XML Spring-Config file

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">  
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/test.htm" access="hasRole('USER') or hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('DBA')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/welcome.htm" access="hasRole('USER') or hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('DBA')" />        
        <form-login />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager >
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" 
                users-by-username-query=
                "SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD, ENABLED FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME=?"
                authorities-by-username-query=
                "SELECT USERNAME, AUTHORITY FROM AUTHORITIES WHERE USERNAME=?"
                />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

The dataSource bean in the xml file is not able to find the main dataSource bean in the java file.

Comment: Could you post your code hear or show us more detail?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. Should I put in any more files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get this configuration working, simply add this to your Spring XML config :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.your.package" />
```

This line tells Spring to load your @Configuration annotated classes from the package "com.your.package" (assuming that the DataConfig class is in this package).

By the way, don't forget to add Spring context XSD location :

```
<beans:beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                             http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">  

<context:component-scan base-package="com.your.package" />
<!-- some other configuration -->
```

Answer (score 0):

As another answer points out make sure you have:

```
> In order to get this configuration working, simply add this to your
> Spring XML config :
> 
> <context:component-scan base-package="com.your.package" /> This line
> tells Spring to load your @Configuration annotated classes from the
> package "com.your.package" (assuming that the DataConfig class is in
> this package).
```

While you are at it make sure you have:

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

I am new to Spring, but wonder if dataSource as a name is unique.

I would try two things, annotate your datasource as primary like so:

```
@Primary
@Bean(name = "dataSource" )
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
```

If that didn't work I would try a different name and point to it in the Security Config:

```
@Bean(name = "myDataSource" )
        public DataSource getDataSource() {
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think `@Primary` is only necessary if there are multiple data sources, to avoid conflict. And yes, I had tried to change the name of the bean at first, but it just couldn't find the annotated ones. Also, the `annotation-config` tag was there since the beginning.